# Remove last new line character of a file in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, cmd

I have around 1340 * 2 GB files in recursive directories. I need to remove the last new line character (only once even if it has multiple new line characters) of every file if exists.
Since these are huge files, please let me know the way to delete the last new line character without reading entire file into memory, something similar to sed command `sed '$ { /^$/ d}' *`

Any help will be highly appreciated. Please see me as novice to batch and windows

Comment: To remove the last two bytes for `CRLF` without rewriting the entire file can be done by truncating the file with a real programming language AIUI.  Batch files and sed will have to rewrite the entire 2 terabytes+

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
sed 'N; $!P; $!D; $s/\n//'
```